# How do I get an array of objects from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

When I get all items from a JSON table in Firebase, it returns them as **object of objects**.

How do I get Firebase to return me an array of objects so that it works nicely with my `ngFor`?

I'm using angular 2 beta and typescript with Firebase.

**This is the current structure returned from Firebase:**

```
 {{"item": ""}, {"item": ""}, {"item": ""}}
```

**I want this (array of objects):**

```
 [{"item": ""}, {"item": ""}, {"item": ""}}]
```

**This is my firebase code that works:**

```
 var query = this.refJob.orderByChild('status').equalTo('Active'); 

query.on('value', (snap) => {               
    resolve(snap.val());    
});
```

Is there something I can do after `equalTo` to organise the results into an array?

**Current bug:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order them into an array on the client-side.

```
var query = this.refJob.orderByChild('status').equalTo('Active'); 
var array = [];
query.on('value', (snap) => {
  snap.forEach((child) => {
     var item = {};
     item._key = snap.key();
     array.push(item));
  });
});
```

Also, don't use promises with `.on()`, because `.on()` can/will be called several times, whereas promises only get called once.

If you want to use something like promises for Firebase and Angular 2, look into using Observables.

Comment: I've tried your code and it returns this "[Q]" with loads of weird lists in the array and not an array of my objects

Comment: I've added above the screen shot of the console for your code

Comment: That's a FirebaseDataSnapshot, it looks weird because the property names are minified for performance. If you call `.val()` the snapshot will return the object. The snapshot is good to keep around because it holds the key and other helpful functions. I've updated my code to show a trick you can do to get the item with the key.